# How can I pass individual `curvature` arguments in `ggplot2` `geom_curve` function?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a `df` with two curve definitions, each consists of two points and a curvature value. The goal is to plot two individual curves using `ggplot2` `geom_curve` (or an alternative).

I can generate my expected output using:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(0,.2), y = c(0,.3), xend = c(1,.4), yend = c(1,.6), curvature = c(-.2,.4))
ggplot(df) + geom_curve(data = df[1, ], aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend), curvature = df$curvature[1]) + geom_curve(data = df[2, ], aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend), curvature = df$curvature[2])
```

[image]

*But this is not really a solution, since in my real case I have lot more curves (and I don't know how many in advance).*

**How can I pass an individual `curvature` argument to the `geom_curve` call?**

---

I tried:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(0,0), y = c(0,0), xend = c(1,1), yend = c(1,1), curvature = c(-.2,.8))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df) + geom_curve(aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend, curvature = curvature))
```

This plots both curves on top of each other and throws an additional warning:

> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: curvature

---

So I tried:

```
ggplot(df) + geom_curve(aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend), curvature = curvature)
```

This throws an error:

> Error in layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomCurve,  : 
>     object 'curvature' not found

---

So I tried to explicitly pass the `curvature` colon:

```
ggplot(df) + geom_curve(aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend), curvature = df$curvature)
```

This as well throws an error:

> Error in seq.default(0, dir * maxtheta, dir * maxtheta/(ncp + 1)) :
>   'to' muss Länge 1 haben In addition: Warning messages: 1: In if
>   (curvature == 0) { :   the condition has length > 1 and only the first
>   element will be used 2: In if (curvature > 0) hand <- "right" else
>   hand <- "left" :   the condition has length > 1 and only the first
>   element will be used

---

From @markus' solution I learned, that we can pass `lists` to a `ggplot` object, so I tried:

```
ggplot(df) + 
  lapply(df$curvature, function(i) {
    geom_curve(aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend), curvature = i) }
  )
```

But this plots each curve with both `curvature` argument:

[image]

---

**How can I pass that `curvature` argument individually for each row?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**update**

You might split your data first and then use `lapply` to iterate over the resulting list which we'll feed to the `data` argument of `geom_curve()`

```
df2 <- data.frame(x = c(0,.2), y = c(0,.3), xend = c(1,.4), yend = c(1,.6), curvature = c(-.2,.4))
ggplot() + 
  lapply(split(df2, 1:nrow(df)), function(dat) {
    geom_curve(data = dat, aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend), curvature = dat["curvature"]) }
  )
```

[image]

**original ansewr**

`curvature` is not an aesthetic, as you have noted. You can add a list to `ggplot()`, to get it work

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(0,0), y = c(0,0), xend = c(1,1), yend = c(1,1), curvature = c(-.2,.8))
ggplot(df) + 
  lapply(df$curvature, function(i) {
    geom_curve(aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend), curvature = i) }
    )
```

[image]

From `help("+.gg")`

> **What can you add?**
>
> ...
>
> You can also supply a list, in which case each element of the list will be added in turn.

---

If you have other parameters that you want to show in your plot - each line might be coloured differently, is of different size etc. - use `Map`

Modified data

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(0,0), y = c(0,0), xend = c(1,1), yend = c(1,1), curvature = c(-.2,.8),
                  colour = c("red", "blue"))
```

Plot

```
ggplot(df1) + 
  Map(function(i, col) {
    geom_curve(aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend), curvature = i, colour = col) },
    i = df1$curvature, col = df1$colour
  )
```

Result

[image]

Comment: Might also be helpful to apply over groups rather than rows depending on application

Answer (score 1):

You could use a for loop to build up your ggplot call as a text string and evaluate the string once the for loop finishes.

```
graphString <- "ggplot(df) "
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  newCurve <- paste(" + geom_curve(data = df[",i,", ], aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend), curvature = df$curvature[",i,"])", sep="")
  graphString <- paste(graphString, newCurve,sep="")
}

eval(parse(text = graphString))
```

Comment: What would be the advantage of this? Cause I guess it will still call geom_curve `nrow(df)` times