# Looping over variable in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following code produces two lines as desired

```
p <- ggplot()
p <- p + geom_line(aes(x=c(0,1),y=c(0,1)))
p <- p + geom_line(aes(x=c(0,1),y=c(0,2)))
```

[image]

Replacing this with a loop only results in one line

```
p <- ggplot()
for(i in 1:2){
    p <- p + geom_line(aes(x=c(0,1),y=c(0,i)))
}
```

[image]

How can I fix this? I want to add an arbitrary number of lines to my plot.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55627528/how-can-i-pass-individual-curvature-arguments-in-ggplot2-geom-curve-functi ? Add a list to your plot and use `lapply` to create that list. `p + lapply(1:2, function(i) { geom_line(aes(x=c(0,1),y=c(0,i))) })` The link provides some examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop saves 2 lines, but with variable `i`, not value of `i`, and when you call `p`, `i==2` so both lines are identical.
You can insert value instead of variable name by `!!` from `dplyr`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
p <- ggplot()
for(i in 1:3) {
  p <- p + geom_line(aes(x=c(0,1),y=c(0,!!i)))
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain why ggplot2 doesn't use the value of i? This is completely counter intuitive to me.

Comment: You are welcome. It is not clear for me also. I checked `summary(p)` and saw 2 similar mappings. If some guru can explain it, I'd like to know also.